# Raspberry Pi 5 suddenly won't turn on

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have an RPI 5. I have the original RPI 5 charger. I have mounted the Active Cooler. Everything was working fine until it wasn't. Now I can't turn the RPI on. The red Power LED is lit.
I am booting from a USB-stick.

Reformatted the the USB. Took out charger and put it back in. Tried holding the power button in for a couple of seconds. Tried to run USB with EEPPROM loader.

I hope one of you can help me.

Comment: Better to post on [raspberrypi.se] - just be sure to read the guidelines there first and provide all relevant details. Off topic here though - unrelated to programming.